# Laravel 5.5 downloads

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, download, controller

I have a problem with a forced download:

In my page I have a line of code:

```
@php
  $pg = "/downloadWirebird/".$mag->PDF;
@endphp
<a href="{{ $pg }}">@fa('download')</a>&nbsp;&nbsp
```

In my web.php file I have:

```
Route::get('/downloadWirebird/{file}','DownloadsController@downloadWirebird');
```

I then have the following method in my controller:

```
public function downloadWirebird($file)
 {
 $file_path = public_path('Wirebird/').$file;
 return response()->download($file_path);
 }
```

but I am getting a response

> Symfony \ Component \ HttpFoundation \ File \ Exception \ FileNotFoundException
>   The file "/home/sites/sthelena.uk.net/public_html/work/public/Wirebird" does not exist

It seems to ignore the file itself.

Any help will be gratefully appreciated.

Comment: Is `$file` set? Perhaps you have another route by the same name that is conflicting? Try to `var_dump()` or `dd()` `$file` and `$file_path`.

Comment: Yes it is set. The link equates to http://main.sthelena.uk.net/downloadWirebird/Wirebird001.pdf and I am certain there is no other route.

Comment: The link you provided has different code than the one you posted. Route is going to `FrontController@downloadWirebird($id)` which accepts an ID instead of a file name, however the error I get is the one you posted. Is the code that you posted supposed to be on the site that you are linking to in your previous comment?

Answer (score 0):

A little bit of fiddling around and I have sorted it.

The view code is

```
  @php
    $pg = "/downloadWirebird/".$mag->PDF;
  @endphp
  <a href="{{ $pg }}">@fa('download')</a>&nbsp;&nbsp
```

The route is

```
Route::get('/downloadWirebird/{file}','DownloadsController@downloadWirebird');
```

and the controller is

```
public function downloadWirebird($file)
 {
  $file_path = public_path('Wirebird/').$file;
  return response()->download($file_path);
 }
```

Comment: I can't see what you changed

Comment: No I definitely uploaded it. Confused! But it works now!